# Passing placeholder variables in maven command line parameters

Tags: maven

I'd like to reference a property defined in my settings.xml file in a maven command line parameter as a placeholder variable that would be resolved at runtime.

Typically for the maven deploy plugin both the credentials and URL of the maven remote repository are stored in the settings.xml file :

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>a_user</username>
      <password>xxxxxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <properties>
    <mvn.repository.snapshots>https://my.maven.repository</mvn.repository.snapshots>
  </properties>
```

and I want to pass them to the deploy / release plugin :

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshots::default::@{mvn.repository.snapshots}
```

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried with `${mvn.repository.snapshots}`? For some reason, the properties in our `settings.xml` are enclosed in a profile (I do not really remember why but I think it is necessary).

Comment: I tried, but so far all I got was : `bash: snapshots::default::${mvn.repository.snapshots}: bad substitution`